# Is it safe when i use HTML code inside php code?

Tags: php, html

I use HTML code inside php like below :

```
            echo '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon 
             glyphicon-pencil w3-large" name="topic_subject"> subject</i>
             </span>
              <br />
              <textarea name="post_content" id="editor1"></textarea>
              <br />
              <div class="w3-col s1 m1 l1"><p></p></div>
              <div class="w3-left">
              <button class = "w3-button w3-xlarge tableButtons w3-middle" 
              id="save">save</button>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a onclick="history.go(-1);" class="w3-button w3-xlarge 
               tableButtons w3-left">cancel</a>  
              </div>                   
              </form>';
```

I use single quotes Then i use double quotes instead of backslash to escape .
That's way is it safe or no ?

Comment: Small correction, use mysqli_real_escape_string(), mysql is deprecated. Your code is 100% safe, don't worry, no problem when you only want to print text on page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Safe in what matter? In the PHP way, yes, because you just echo a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe indeed, but not because you use single quotes. Echoing this string would be the same result as making a normal html page. Outputting html from your php is usually safe as long as you know what you output.

Using single quotes does provide an advantage when posting a html string though, that is because with single quotes you don't have the escape the double quotes in your html.

E.g.: `echo '<span class="input-group-addon">';` would become `echo "<span class=\"input-group-addon\">";` if you were to use double quotes.

Using data directly from your html form to query or filter is a bigger risk because it's prone to SQL injection. For more information I'd like to refer you to [an article on the PHP.net website](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) on what it is and how to prevent it.

Comment: "Using single quotes does provide an advantage when posting a html string though, that is because with single quotes you don't have the escape the double quotes in your html" — Swap every instance of "single" with "double" and that makes just as much sense.

Answer (score -1):

This should be perfectly safe, since you're just outputting code. If you were taking code and storing it on a database, however, you should use <strike>`mysql_real_escape_string()`</strike> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.

Just to be clear, this is an unofficial opinion and if some crazy new hack comes out, don't blame me! haha

Comment: when i storing data in database i use prepared statements so i think it's safe without using mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Sorry, you are quite right, not sure what I was thinking with that one. Edited